# Explanation about hough_line_peaks after using hough_line

Tags: python, hough-transform

Could anyone please explain why after using `h,theta,d = hough_line(image)` which will detect the angles in an image do we have to use this for loop `for _, a, d in zip(*hough_line_peaks(h, theta, d)):
        angle.append(a) #angle is a list` to add the angles to the list?
Since the `hough_line(image)` will store the angles in the theta variable why can't we use it to retrieve the angles and add them to a list?

Here's a snippet of the code to detect angles of lines in an image:

```
image = imread(file_name)  
image = np.mean(image, axis=2)  

h, theta, d = hough_line(image)  

angle = []  

for _, a, d in zip(*hough_line_peaks(h, theta, d)):
        angle.append(a)  

angle = [a * 180 / np.pi for a in angle]
```

Comment: Nobody is likely going to answer this question on the account of the fact that its not a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). First if these were calls to actual `opencv` functions the Hough transform signature would look like: `h, theta, d = HoughLines(image, rho=1, theta=1, threshold=1)` but what is happening here with `hough_line` makes me thing this is a call to some other function not to `cv2`. Same with `hough_line_peaks`. The `zip(*...)` construct is suspicious as well, why unpack and then repack with `zip` again. If you get us something we can try - maybe

Comment: the hough_line and hough_line_peaks that I used are from the scikit-image API not openCV.

Comment: Like I said, without imports or tags its impossible to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what's happening here is the following:

- detect all lines on the image using `hough_lines`.

  - this returns accumulator values, angles, in radians, and distance from origin, let's say for a 1000 peaks in Hough space it identifies as lines.
- select only the most prominent lines among all detected lines

  - those peaks whose distance from origin is at least 9 "resolution" steps away from another similar peak
  - those peaks which theta coordinate is at least 10 angle "resolution" steps away from another similar peak
  - those whose accumulator count is larger than max_count/2 in the whole Hough space
  - this picks lets say 200 out of the original 1000 lines as more likely to actually be lines in the image.
  - this is effectively a filter on all the returned `hough_lines` that picks those that are most likely to be lines. So you also get back accumulator values, angles, in radians, and distance from origin.
- Then you copy all the angles you got back from `hough_line_peaks` into a new `list` called `a`
- then you use another `for` loop to iterate through a and create a new list called `angle` in which you store the values from `a` converted to `degrees`

So as you see there's probably room for improvement. First there is no need to copy the entire list of angles. Second, you're actually doing more harm like that because now you can not use vectorized operations that numpy gives you. The array returned from `hough_line_peaks` is a numpy `ndarray` which you can just multiply directly.

```
import skimage

image = skimage.io.imread(file_name)  
image = np.mean(image, axis=2)  

h, theta, d = skimage.transform.hough_line(image)
bestH, bestTheta, bestD = skimage.transform.hough_line_peaks(h, theta, d)
angle = bestTheta * (180/np.pi)
```

Should give you the same results, and probably a bit faster too. This whole line `zip(*hough_line_peaks(h, theta, d))` should always be suspect because `*` is called the "unpacking" operator. So given a tuple, list, or any other iterable `(a, b, c)` the unpacking operator unpacks the iterable `*(a, b, c) --> a, b, c` so then zipping them back again just packs them back again `*(a, b, c) --> a, b, c --> (a, b, c)`. These constructs should always be a little bit suspicious. The underline in that for loop `for _, a, b in...` is just throwing that value away as nameless. And the final `[ a for a in...]` construct is called list comprehension and works exactly as a `for` loop but is just syntactic sugar to make things more readable when possible.

### EDIT

Answer to extra question in comment. Lets say:

```
>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> a
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

>>> a.mean(axis=0)
array([2., 3.])

>>> a.mean(axis=1)
array([1.5, 3.5])
```

So the `mean` on axis 0 is doing `(1+3)/2=2` and `(2+4)/2=3` - so effectively `axis=0` is the vertical slice across `a`. The `axis=1` is then a horizontal slice across `a` so that `(1+2)/2=1.5` and `(3+4)/2=3.5`. The same goes for any larger dimension matrix of elements with addendum that you just have more dimensions. So for 2D matrix its vertical+horizontal for 3D it will be vertical+horizontal+depth. So axis 2 is summing on "depth".

Why this is necessary is that `hough_lines` can only work with intensity data. It doesn't understand colors. But in a color image each pixel is actually 3 numbers `(r, b, g)` representing the red, blue and green channel intensities. The mix of these intensities eventually produce color on display. So the `mean(axis=2)` line is instructing numpy to take the 3D matrix representing an image and return to you a 2D matrix where each pixel intensity value has been replaced by the average of the 3 color intensity values.

So an color image:

```
index      1           2     ....
     ___________________________________
  1  | [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5, 6] ...
  2  | [7, 8, 9] .          ...
  .  |     .       .
  .  |     .         .
  .  |     .           .
```

becomes a grayscale image:

```
index  1  2
    ______________________________
  1 |  2  5 ...
  2 |  8  . ...
  3 |  .   .
    |  .    .
    |  .     .
    |
```

Comment: thanks mate, really helpfull and really appreciated :)

Comment: would you know what does the ```image = np.mean(image,axis=2)``` do? i read that it compute the mean according to the axis but what good does it do in the algorithm?

Comment: @DanielK Edited my answer.